# ebook formats and mobiles

Tags: android, ios, pdf, epub

I have an app for android and iOS. I want to add in app option, which allow user select book from list and read it.
List of available books will be load from server.
Now i wondering which book format to choose. First i'm thinking about pdf, but it has not-flexible reflowing for different screens(books contains sheets and formules). Maybe .epub would be good choice?

ps. is this possible to prevent user copy loaded book files?
Should i load files only in memory(without saving on sd), but how then work with files exceeded ram memory?
have you know any good iOS and android libraries, sdk for reading ebook files?

Comment: If you are building the app, you can use any format you want. I'd agree with you about avoiding PDF because of the reflow problems and I'd probably recommend EPUB since a simple book is basically (and I'm simplifying) just a zip file of HTML files. All of your other issues you're just going to have to test and play with per-device.

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same SDK options and found this for ePub:

http://skyepub.net/downloads/

There are handfuls of PDF SDKs.  Throw a dart at the internet and see what it hits, however, I would like to know which ones have risen to the top (e.g., the top 3).

Still looking for .mobi (Kindle's format).